# django 1.9 how to keep session after change password through ajax request

Tags: django, session, authentication, passwords

I have a function to update user data by ajax

```
def ajax_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    update_form = forms.UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if update_form.is_valid():
        update_form.save()
        response['status'] = 'success'
        return JsonResponse(response)
```

and a UserUpdateForm

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['password']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(UserUpdateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password_1'])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

After set_password executed and save the instance, It returned 'success' message.

However, When I reload the page Its session was expired

Is there a way to keep session after change password by ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.update_session_auth_hash). You should use the `update_session_auth_hash()` function.

But in this case you should also update the session cookie in your javascript since a new hash is generated.

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thanks!